# Вывод картинки при исполнении условия

Tags: javascript

нужно вывести картинку при выполнении условия, если условие не выполнилось вывести другую. делаю так:

```js
function one() {
  if (true) {
    let soundRight = new Audio("audio/right.wav");
    soundRight.play();
    let layer = document.querySelectorAll('.answer');
    //layer.innerHTML = "<img src='img/star1.svg'>";
    layer.style.width = '20px';
    layer.style.height = '20px';
    layer.style.backgroundImage = "img/star.svg";
    document.getElementsByClassName(".answer").appendChild(layer);
  } else {
    let soundWrong = new Audio("audio/error.wav");
    soundWrong.play();
    let layer1 = document.querySelectorAll('.answer');
    //layer1.innerHTML = "<img src='img/star2.svg'>";
    layer1.style.width = '20px';
    layer1.style.height = '20px';
    layer1.style.backgroundImage = "img/star2.svg";
    document.getElementsByClassName(".answer").appendChild(layer);
  }
```

```html
<div class="answer"></div>
```

так не работает... подскажите как правильно? чистый js

Comment: Что значить if (true)? должно  же быть какое-либо условие, в вашем коде, блок if всегда будет выполняться.

Comment: да, там есть условие на самом деле. само условие здесь не важно, поэтому не стала его полностью писать.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` выводит массив объедков (видимо в этом проблема)

Я рекомендую использовать [JQuery](https://jquery.com/), смотри как просто: `$('.answer:first');` подробнее по селекторам - [тута](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

```js
const one=(tf=false)=>{
    let alayer = document.querySelectorAll('.answer')[0];
    let sound = {};
    if(tf){
        sound = new Audio('audio/right.wav');
        alayer.style.backgroundImage = 'img/star.svg';
    }else{
        sound = new Audio('audio/error.wav');
        alayer.style.backgroundImage = 'img/star2.svg';
    }
    sound.play();
    alayer.style.width = '20px';
    alayer.style.height = '20px';
    document.getElementsByClassName('.answer')[0].appendChild(alayer);
};

one(true);
```